# Python 2.7 Tkinter redraw widget inside if

Tags: python, tkinter

I have problem with my Tkinter code in Python 2.7. I have main window with one widget (button). I want to redraw window (and change value of variable -> add one widget) after click on the button. Where is problem? I think that problem can be, that every loop of mainloop change variable to 0. Thank you!

```
from Tkinter import *

def function():
    global variable
    variable = 0
    main.update()

variable = 0
main = Tk() #New Tk window

if variable == 1:
    Checkbutton(main, text="test").pack()

Button(main, text="Change", command=function).pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set variable to 1, and you should use functions (and classes) when working with GUIs.

```
from Tkinter import *
main = Tk() #New Tk window
variable = 0

def function():
    global variable
    variable = 1
    newThing()

def newThing(): 
   global variable
   if variable==1:
       Checkbutton(main, text="test").pack()
   variable = 0

Button(main, text="Change", command=function).pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: My primary code is in OOP, i want to write simple example.
So it isn't way to recall if without function. And sorry i have mistake in function() i mean variable = 1.